# Is it safe to store extremely complicated Password in SHA1?

Tags: api, security, session, passwords, token

Is it safe to hash extremely complicated password (longer than 25 chars, any ascii chars even binary) with SHA1 ?

Actually, the password represent a tokenID but I don't want to store it like this in the database, i prefer to hash it for more security.

The password (token) is valid only for 14 Days and I need to hash it the most faster as possible (so no way to use something like bcrypt)

What must be the ideal length of the Password (token) ?

Comment: Password hashing is supposed to be slow. If you think you need it to be fast, then you most likely need another solution ... Verify once, then switch to random tokens? Or maybe it's not a password at all? Sounds like it's not ... a random token is not the same thing as a password. Token handling is usually automated and the user doesn't even think about them, while passwords are supposed to be manually input by users. Either way, SHA-1 is not supposed to be used for anything security-related today.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, no.  "Complicated" it may be, but **cryptographically random** it probably is not.

A bare minimum would be applying an [RFC2104 HMAC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104) with a secret key (pepper); however, a more appropriate alternative that can, if you absolutely insist, still be quite fast would be to use PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-256 and ignore all rules of security regarding a sufficiently high iteration count, i.e. choose an iteration count of 10, instead of 10,000.

For password/token hashing, of course, never request more bytes of PBKDF2 output than the native hash function provides - 20 for SHA-1, 32 for SHA-256, 64 for SHA-512.

I have several example implementations of PBKDF2 at [my Github repository](https://github.com/Anti-weakpasswords) that may help, and there are others in other languages, of course.

Use a cryptographically random per-password (per-token) salt.

Comment: thanks ! but i think that even with a very very ultra fast SHA1, to decript a random 20 char pwd (ie: 255^20 combinations = 1.3E+48) it's will be very long and the pwd is valid only 14 days. i will take a loog at your Github, great job !

Comment: Your TokenId is nearly certainly not the same strength as a 20 character cryptographically random string.  As I mentioned, the bare minimum would be to use HMAC-SHA1.  How many millions of checks per minute are you expecting to need?